# Inverter valores de um vetor para outro vetor

Tags: java, netbeans, array

Estou no segundo semestre da faculdade, estamos aprendendo vetor, e estou muito perdido na lista de exercicios.

Um exercicio pede para que o usuário, digite 5 elementos para um vetor, e logo em seguida, tenho que pegar esses elementos, mandar para outro vetor, só que com ordem invertida. Como posso fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
vetor_original [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vetor_cppia [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
int[] vetor_original = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int tamanhoVetorOriginal = vetor_original.length;
int[] vetor_copia = new int[tamanhoVetorOriginal];
int tamanhoVetorOriginalZeroBased = tamanhoVetorOriginal - 1;
for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetorOriginal; i++) {
    vetor_copia[i] = vetor_original[tamanhoVetorOriginalZeroBased - i];
    System.out.print(vetor_copia[i]);
}
```

---

**Saída**: `54321`

---

## Explicação

- `int tamanhoVetorOriginal`: representa o tamanho do vetor original. Ou seja, `5`;
- `int[] vetor_copia = new int[tamanhoVetorOriginal]`: cria um novo vetor/array com o mesmo tamanho do `vetor_original`;
- `int tamanhoVetorOriginalZeroBased`: arrays são estruturas `zero-based`. Isso significa que sua contagem de registros nunca começa do número 1, mas sim do 0. Ex: se você fizer `System.out.println(vetor_original[1])` será impresso `2` e não `1`, pois o registro `1` está na posição `vetor_original[0]`. Criei essa variável para usar como um pequeno truque para percorrer o array. Se o tamanho do `vetor_original` é `5`, se formos percorrer de 0 á 5 teremos 6 posições: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Por isso subtraio 1 do tamanho original, fazendo com que essa variável fique com o valor `4` e quando formos percorrer teremos: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` -> 5 posições;
- `vetor_copia[i] = vetor_original[tamanhoVetorOriginalZeroBased - i]`: itera o `vetor_original` de trás para frente. Ex: assumindo `i = 0`, teremos: `vetor_copia[0] = vetor_original[tamanhoVetorOriginalZeroBased - 0]` -> na posição `0` do `vetor_copia` é atribuído o valor da última posição do `vetor_original`;

Answer (score 0):

Você cai em uma situação onde você pode não saber quais são os números que são digitados então você pode fazer assim de forma automática:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Agora a ordem invertida");
        for (int j = a.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.println(a[j]);
        }

    }
```

Primeiro eu faço um for pra imprimir os valores originais e logo após crio outro pra mostrar de forma invertida.